# How Can the Users Make a "Playlist" of Posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, audio

I have an audio website and I want to allow users to make custom playlists from posts.

I am using posts as Albums which contains the Tracks. I thought of creating a custom post type and using it to hold a user select playlist based on the default posts.

Is this a good idea or is there a better way to allow users to create custom playlist.

Notes:

- I had a look at [this tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/fast-buddypress-development/). It is what I'm looking for but for individual tracks in the post.
- The audio is stored in arrays in custom fields, i.e `custom_audio{ audio=>"name", url=>"www.text.com"}`

Comment: Can you point me what do you mean " wordpress post as a album" what it means? you place in your post a links to mp3 or you upload a mp3 (any other format) to your post?

Comment: i am using the post custom fields to contain all the tracks in the album, each post contains different albums

Comment: This question seems overly broad.

Comment: am storing audio in arrays in custom fields, i.e custom_auido{audio=>"name", url=>"www.text.com"}, would it be good practice to use custom post type to store users custom playlist or create a custom database table.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is to create a relationship between a Custom Post Type and the Post type.

If your users have editing capability for the CPT, then yes, it's a good idea to use the CPT's to hold the information about the Albums (normal posts).

The easiest/fastest solution is to use a plugin.

[Posts to Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) is meant exclusively for this (my emphasis):

> This plugin allows you to create many-to-many relationships between
> posts of any type: post, page, custom etc. A few example use cases:
>
> - manually curated lists of related posts
> - post series
> - products connected to retailers
> - etc.
>
> Additionally, you can create many-to-many
> relationships between posts and users. So, you could also implement:
>
> - **favorite posts of users**
> - multiple authors per post
> - etc.

---

And another one is [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/). As I'm a regular user, I can illustrate its use for this case.

**Create** a Field Group with the following configuration:

[image: advanced-custom-fields configuration]
<sup>*click to enlarge*</sup>

**That** results in this:

[image: advanced-custom-fields result]

The result snapshot have a little trick though. The normal box that ACF generates has a very short height.
To modify the box height, use the following code in your theme's `functions.php` file, or a [custom plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Standard_Plugin_Information) which makes this theme independent.

```
/** 
 * ADJUST THE VALUE OF 'playlists' TO THE CUSTOM POST TYPE SLUG
 * ADJUST THE VALUE OF #acf-album_posts TO MATCH THE FIELD NAME 
 */ 
add_action('admin_head-post.php', 'wpse_73351_admin_head');
add_action('admin_head-post-new.php', 'wpse_73351_admin_head');

function wpse_73351_admin_head()
{
    global $post;
    
    // Not our post_type, do nothing
    if ( 'playlists' != $post->post_type )
        return;     
    ?>
        <style>
            #acf-album_posts select {
                height: 400px !important;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
}
```

**Finally**, read the [plugin's documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/relationship/) to see how to grab the `album_posts` field value and play that funky music :)

Comment: thanks for the answer, just wondering would it be possible to link a certain track from the an album (post) to a user, that is saved in the custom fields.

Comment: That's [another question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)... Try first, ask later :)